# Using Phusion/mod_rails

Tags: ruby, apache

I've been looking into using mod_rails (Phusion), but I just wanted to verify this: Once it's installed, I can still serve regular, non-rails apps from the same server without making any changes. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. I'm using Passenger in a project with other PHP projects and it works fine (even some PHP files in your public folder).

You can also set the passenger to start standalone (`passenger start -d` in your rails root folder) and use the `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrite` from Apache to handle it (redirecting the rails requests to the rails app).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can still serve non-rails applications using the same server.

`mod_rails` automatically detects which DocumentRoots are Rails applications by looking for `public`, for example.